# Unable to stringify to JSON - throws cyclic structures error

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

Below is my data object structure as printed out on the console of Safari:

```
_Api (2)
0 {company_code: 64, clerk_code: "RO", clerk_name: "Akshay", list_a: 1, list_b: 0}
1 {company_code: 64, clerk_code: "SA", clerk_name: "Lokur", list_a: 0, list_b: 1}
```

Now when I use `JSON.stringify(data)` in order to send this to server side code from `Jquery $.ajax` method, I am getting following error:

```
TypeError: JSON.stringify cannot serialize cyclic structures.
```

Confused how my data is cyclic..!

Any clues anyone?

Comment: What's the source of the data? Some libraries (like Axios) augment the returned value in a semi-transparent way resulting in some cycles. However when you log them, you may not see what they added.

Comment: what does `Object.entries(<data>)` return?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries

Comment: Can you show us how data is being generated and what the input is?

Comment: Clearly it's not that data: https://jsbin.com/goxetig/edit?js,console. Maybe you convert to JSON you received to a **JavaScript** object's array somehow.. Can you show us the full code from the first ajax call (get) to the second call (post to the server)?

Comment: Sending data via jQuery [ajax request](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) can be done with plain objects, no reason to stringify anything.

Comment: Might be able to stringify it like this: `JSON.stringify(Array.from(data))`

Comment: @IvanRubinson and @LajosArpad This data is sourced from datatables selected rows (datatables.net) `let data = acct_clerk_datatable.rows('.selected').data();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works like this:

```
var data = acct_clerk_datatable.rows('.selected').data().toArray();
var json = JSON.stingify( data );
```

Reference: https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/36669/create-json-string-from-datatable-selected-selected-row